# Remove hits with [this tag] from my results

Tags: support, tags, search

How can I remove all results with a certain tag. Harry Potter and Story Identification need their own Stack site....

---

Answer:

Here's how to **ignore** certain [tags]

Hover on the tag and click the star at the top left of the box twice. Go to the “preferences” tab in your profile and select “Hide questions in your ignored tags”.

Thanks Gilles.

Comment: Harry Potter doesn't need its own site.  It already has questions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter).

Comment: Perhaps you need to search for each tag specifically.

Comment: you might also try -[harry-potter]

Comment: Additionally, to remove [harry-potter] and [story-identification] from the home page, make them ignored tags (hover on the tag and click the star at the top left of the box twice).

Comment: Go to the “preferences” tab in your profile and select “Hide questions in your ignored tags”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to ignore certain [tags]:

Hover on the tag and click the star at the top left of the box twice. Go to the “preferences” tab in your profile and select “Hide questions in your ignored tags”.

Thank you, Gilles.

Answer (score 6):

If you think Harry Potter needs his own site, you can propose the site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Also, I think [the search help here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) already answers your question, if it is regarding excluding tags:

> To exclude results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with - in your query: waffles -unicorns finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while [laurel] -[hardy] includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

So for your example, including `-[harry-potter]` might do the trick.

Comment: "Story Identification" makes up the majority of the hits I skip. Sugest this at that same site?

Comment: @Mazura But keep in mind, there's a process that an approved proposal must go through before it even becomes a beta site, so if you're looking to exclude search results by getting a new site, it won't work, at least not right away.

Comment: I may have to push for an ID site. It is seemingly at least 3\4 of the results if not more.

Comment: @Mazura I updated my answer with a quote from the Search Help page.

Comment: intags:mine returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite.  (i need that backwards) tx for the help link. There is no FAQ button and I'm too obstinate to have gone into a help center ;)

Comment: @Mazura glad I could help!